# Using Dozer framework for object mapping in java

Tags: java, object, mapping, dozer

I am using Dozer framework for my object mapping in java.

Now I got stuck because of the following problem:

Following are my classes:

```
    public class BaseQuestion
    {

        public String question = "";

        public String answer = "";

       /**
        * Getter for question
        */
       public String getQuestion()
       {
         return question;
       }

       /**
        * @Setter for question
        */
       public void setQuestion(String question)
       {
         this.question = question;
       }

       /**
        * Getter for answer
        */
       public String getAnswer()
        {
            return answer;
        }

       /**
        * @Setter for answer
        */
       public void setAnswer(String answer)
       {
        this.answer = answer;
       }

      }


      public class QuestionsMap
      {
              Question[] question;

             public void setQuestion(Question[] question)
             {
               this.question = question;
             }

             public Question[] getQuestion()
             {
                return this.question;
             }
      }

 In the above classes I have to map QuestionsMap class with a HashMap as below:

   Map<String,String> questionsMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
   BaseQuestion[] question=QuestionsMap.getQuestion();
   questionsMap.put(question[0].getQuestion(),question[0].getAnswer());
   questionsMap.put(question[1].getQuestion(),question[1].getAnswer());
   questionsMap.put(question[2].getQuestion(),question[2].getAnswer());
   questionsMap.put(question[3].getQuestion(),question[3].getAnswer());
```

Can any one suggest how can I acheive it using dozer framework.

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use dozer ??? Is this what you are looking for:

```
Map<String,String> questionsMap=new HashMap<String,String>();

for(BaseQuestion baseQuestion : questionMap.getQuestion()){
    questionMap.put(baseQuestion.getQuestion(),baseQuestion.getAnswer());
}
```

Comment: Thnaks for ur answer pgras. 

I want to use dozer bcz I have diffrent data types(like above ones) which must be mapped to a map.